# Generalizing $(^4C_0)^2-(^4C_1)^2+(^4C_2)^2-(^4C_3)^2+(^4C_4)^2=\,^4C_2$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

[image: the question]

[image: the answer]

I got this question, and I have a bit of an issue with part (b). I managed to prove the attached result; however, it does not really fit the above result (as it said generalise the result and then prove). Can anyone assist?

Comment: You surely want to find $$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k{n\choose k}^2.$$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I guess so but I can't seem to generate anything similar to that from the given formula that they told me to expand. I tried values for my formula and it works but there is probably something I'm not seeing to get it to look like the above statement

Comment: You are generalizing incorrectly. Essentially, consider the expression given  in part b, and compute the coefficient of $\frac 1{x^{2n}}$ on both sides using the binomial theorem. The LHS will give you some expression, and the RHS some expression. These must be the same, and their equality is a generalization of the specific case you solved.

Comment: Thank you . I was comparing the coefficients for 1\x^4 but I understand why you took 2n as it fits 1\x^4 when n=2